# I want to repair my digestive system

Tags: digestion

I've been experiencing diarrhea every morning for the past 8 months.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 months is a long time, so should see a doctor. Write down everything you have noticed that has changed (e.g. you may be losing weight, you may have heart palpitations, you may be eating a lot more or your appetite may be a lot less than what it used to be, etc. etc.). Then go to the doctor and mention everything that has changed. The doctor will likely ask a lot of questions, but if you have thought about your symptoms in advance then you are more likely to give the right answer. A potential problem is that when complaints have existed for long, you may get used to certain things causing you to give a wrong answer relating to changes in your body.